# ResolveUrl doesn't seem to work for ../../ when linking to external javascript files with dynamic virtual directories

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

so I've had this problem before. since the virtual directory is dynamic it keeps breaking my javascript links. I used ResolveUrl for them and it seemed to have worked.(this is in an .aspx file)

```
<link href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JQueryPlugins/Tooltip/toolitp.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

however, I have ran into a problem. In another file I have another bunch of javascript links that link to javascript files 2 directories up, so the default would look like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/yui/utilities/utilities.js"></script>
```

the ../../ seems to be messing up resolveUrl so it still cant find the files.

Answer (score 1):

Write some utility function to detect the root path and append with it.

**Ex: GetAppPath()+"/lib/yui/utilities/utilities.js";**

public static string GetAppPath()
        {

```
        return (System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath == "/") ? string.Empty : System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

    }
```

Comment: well, it still doesn't work but it seems as though the developer was changing a few things, hence why it didn't work, but thank you